# How to import source file structure in informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have source file as

```
Customer_ID Customer_Name City
7004 Oracle Mumbai
7001 Microsoft San Francisco
7002 IBM Toronto
7003 Red Hat New york
```

when i import and take deltimated type as SPACE then the value also get seprated by space.for example:- Red Hat,New york,San Francisco.
Could you please help me to get the full name under the one header as in CITY full name San Francisco and New york.Under the Customer_Name Red Hat.

Comment: You cannot do that. Either the values need to be in quotes, or the delimiter should be something else like a tab

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. This is not a delimetered file. It is a fixed width file. You have to import this as a fixed width file defining boundaries.